# How to access two http request on one submit synchronously in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

In this method i am calling two http requests in `callSubmit()` in this `onEmpSubmit()` i added form values and on `loadId()` call api to get latest added employee Id so as per JS asynchronous behaviour its run loadId() first which i want to run after `onEmpSubmit()` 
component.ts

```
 onEmpSubmit(){
     return this.cs.callAPI(formData, "addEmp").subscribe(response => {

          if (response.status === 1) {
            this.myapp.showSuccessAlert = true;
            this.employeeId = response.userId;
            console.log(this.employeeId);
            this.myapp.successMsg = response.message;
            this.myapp.isLoadingResults = false;
            //this.isMapShow = false;
          }
         else {
          console.log("response.message" + response.message);
          this.myapp.showErrorAlert = true;
          this.myapp.errorMsg = response.message;
          this.myapp.isLoadingResults = false;
        }
      });
    }
  loadId(){
  return this.cs.getletestId().subscribe(res =>{
      if(res.status == 1){
        this.apiRes = res.data;
        console.log(res);
      }
    })
  }
  callSubmit(){
   this.onEmpSubmit();
   this.loadId();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches you can take:

- Simpler approach would be converting those observables into a Promise and then awaiting.

```
  onEmpSubmit(){
     return this.cs.callAPI(formData, "addEmp").toPromise();
  }

  loadId(){
  return this.cs.getletestId().toPromise();
  }

  async callSubmit(){
   const employeeResult = await this.onEmpSubmit();
   const id = await this.loadId();
  }
```

You can do the rest of operations later with the awaited results.

- You could use rxjs observable operator like concat to subscribe to observables in order as previous completes.